# HP Procurve 2650 has password set after factory reset

Tags: hp, serial, hp-procurve

I have a problem with HP ProCurve 2650 switch. I don't have a password to it so I did a factory reset (pressing reset and clear buttons for 10 seconds). The problem is it still asks for the password. It restarts but doesn't clear its configuration nor the password.

Answer (score 3):

You may not have correctly reset the device the procedure is

> 1. Simultaneously press the Reset and Clear buttons on the front of the switch with a paperclip.
> 2. Continue to hold the Clear button while releasing the Reset button.
> 3. When the Self Test LED begins to blink, release the Clear button.

There is no default password.

[HP Procurve Switch 2650 Installation and Getting Started Guide](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/j489990001.pdf)

Comment: I did exactly as you described above. Self Test begins to blink, device reboots but after that still asks for the password.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation then.

Comment: What documentation? Do you mean  Installation and Getting Started Guide?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've not seen any hardware that old in a while, but modern HP switches have the following configuration options available to them:

```
no front-panel-security password-clear
no front-panel-security factory-reset
```

This protection cannot be bypassed, so if the password is forgotten when that command is enabled, you're out of luck. (Though this sounds like a good excuse to upgrade your switch!)

It looks like this feature was added after initial software release, according to [this ASG excerpt from 2005](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/Security-Oct2005-59906024-Chap02-Passwords.pdf). The [ASG from 2003](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/59906024e01-Security-Guide.pdf) makes no mention of it.